# T4A Slip received by student. What is it?

Tags: income-tax, canada, form-t4a

I'm in my first year of university and received a T4A Slip from the Government of Canada in the amount of $1000. Doing some digging I found it relates to Pensions and such but am now even more confused as to why I got it.

Any ideas as to why I received it or what exactly it is?

Comment: did you ask your parents? Did you get a scholarship, student loan or have a job?

Comment: Did you have, say, $1000 saved in an RRSP? Did you cash it in?

Comment: My bet is on scholarship. Although it's not taxable perhaps it gives you RRSP room?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

T4A is "Statement of Pension, Retirement, Annuity, and **Other Income**"

Other Income includes scholarship and certain grant.

If the amount is exactly $890 and the payer is Ministry of Training, Colleges and Universities, it is *30% Off Ontario Tuition Grant*.

If the amount is exactly $1000 and the payer is Canada Student Loans Program, it is *Canada Student Grant for Persons from Low-Income Families*.

if the payer is University of X, it is scholarship received between Sep 2014 and Dec 2014.